# External scripts with Polymer custom element

Tags: polymer

I'm creating a custom element with Polymer to embed a Medium profile card. The embed code provided by Medium is,

```
<script async src="https://static.medium.com/embed.js"></script>
<a class="m-profile" href="https://medium.com/@pankajparashar">Pankaj Parashar</a>
```

The code for my custom element looks like this,

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script async src="https://static.medium.com/embed.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="medium-card">
    <template>
        <a class="m-profile" href="https://medium.com/@pankajparashar">Pankaj Parashar</a>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('medium-card', {});
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I've noticed that the script doesn't load when it is included inside the custom element. Hence, I've added the external script `embed.js` outside the `polymer-element` tag. Although, the external script now loads, it doesn't embed the profile card at all.

Is something wrong the way the external script is used? I do not really want to use the iframe technique either.

Comment: One thing you should do is remove the `async` attr. Since you're in an HTML Import, you're already async to the main document parser. Also, we typically wrap .js dependencies in their own import (e.g. https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element/blob/master/firebase-import.html). That way, if other parts of your app need to use embed.js, they can load it via an import and the browser will de-dupe the URL. As to the actual problem, it's likely because embed.js can't find the `<a>` internal to your shadow dom.